# CanCan and ActiveRecord associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, cancan, cancancan

I have the following line in my Ability.rb

```
can :index, :calls, :store => { area_id: user.area_id }
```

In calls_controller.rb

```
load_and_authorize_resource :store
load_and_authorize_resource :call, :through => :store

def index
    @calls = Call.accessible_by(current_ability, :index)
end
```

In the model call.rb

```
belongs_to :store
```

Yet when I try to access @calls in a view I get the following SQL error

```
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'store.area_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `calls`.* FROM `calls` INNER JOIN `stores` ON `stores`.`id` = `calls`.`store_id` WHERE `store`.`area_id` = 4 LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

This is because the SQL query should have "WHERE `stores`.`area_id` = 4".  Is this a problem with CanCan or do I have something setup wrong?
I'm using CanCan 2.0, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the ability to:

```
can :index, Call, :store => { area_id: user.area_id }
```

Comment: Interesting.  That doesn't error, but it allows the user to see all calls, not just those in area 4.  I'm building a new project here, so there's hardly anything in Ability.rb or in any controllers which might interfere afaik.

Comment: I'm sure that syntax doesn't work. Compare:   can [:read, :index], :calls, :id => 55866,  and   can [:read, :index], Call, :id => 55866.  The latter lets you see all Calls, the former just the one

Comment: not sure what's wrong but why don't you try `cancancan` since `cancan` support is dropped for a while now and this could be an old issue!

Answer (score 0):

If you limit the stores a user can see

```
  if !user.area_id.nil? and user.area_id != 0 then
    user_stores = Store.where(:area_id => user.area_id)
  end
```

Then you can pass an array in the condition

```
  can [:read, :index], :stores, :id => user_stores
  can [:read, :index, :create, :update], [:calls, :change_requests], :store_id => user_stores
```

That works as required.